# Unhealthy load balancer on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a couple of services and the loadbalancers work fine. Now I keep facing an issue with a service that runs fine, but when a loadbalancer is applied I cannot get it to work, because one service seams to be unhealty, but I cannot figure out why. How can I get that service healthy?

[image]

Here are my k8s yaml.
Deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: api-production
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: api
      labels:
        app: api
        role: backend
        env: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: eu.gcr.io/foobar/api:1.0.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readinez
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
        env:
        - name: ENVIRONMENT
          value: "production"
        - name: GIN_MODE
          value: "release"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: api
          containerPort: 8080
```

Service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
    role: backend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
  - name: external
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.bar.io
    secretName: api-tls
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Are the pods from your deployment running fine? Does the service have correct endpoints associated?

Comment: Since only one `Service` appears to be in error (the one whose NodePort is 32364), please include the actual `kubectl get -o yaml service $foo` for that specific `Service` (although I **strongly** suspect it is the `name: external` one, because your `container:` has no `port: 80` matching `targetPort: 80`)

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out the port mixups. I have now changed all of this. The strange thing now is though, that it everything was healthy and now its gone to unknown again (the one that was unhealthy before). Could this be caused by kube-lego trying to obtain a certificate. Currently I have hit a rate limit with lets encrypt so it cannot finish?

Comment: Could you confirm that the  issue described [here](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/issues/27) correspond to your case.

Comment: See answer. In my case it was a matter of port configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by configuring the ports in the correct way. Container, Service and LB need (obviously) to be aligned. I also added the `initialDelaySeconds`.

LB:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.foo.io
    secretName: api-tls
  rules:
  - host: api.foo.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 8080
```

Service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
    role: backend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      name: http
```

Deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: api-production
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: api
      labels:
        app: api
        role: backend
        env: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: eu.gcr.io/foobarbar/api:1.0.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /readinez
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
        env:
         - name: ENVIRONMENT
          value: "production"
        - name: GIN_MODE
          value: "release"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```